# BackgroundWorker and Progressbar.Show()

Tags: .net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and C# and try to get my progressbar to show but it doesn't work.

I listen to an event. If it happens I want to do some work and show a progressbar while doing that.

This is what I do:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  ProgressForm form = new ProgressForm();
  new FileWatcher(form).Start();
  Application.Run();
}

ProgressForm:
bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
  this.Show();
  ....
}
```

but nothing shows. Why isn't that working?

thanks
bye juergen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a BGW to display a form, the thread does not have the proper state.  You'll have to use a Thread so you can call its SetApartmentState() method to switch it to STA.  You also need a message loop on the thread to keep the form alive, that requires a call to Application.Run().  And the form must be created on that thread.  Thus:

```
        var t = new Thread(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
```

One big issue with this form is that it cannot be owned by any window on your UI thread.  Giving it the tendency to disappear behind the window of another application.  Also, your UI thread is still dead, its windows will ghost with the "Not Responding" message in their caption bar after a few seconds.

The proper way to do this is the other way around: run the time-consuming code on another thread, a BGW would be a very good choice.  The UI thread should display your progress form.  BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress is ideal to keep the progress bar updated.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!
Now it works. The main problem was that I did this:
Application.Run();
instead of this:
Application.Run(progressbarForm);

And I invoke the progressbar from my backgroundWorker and it shows!

bye juergen

Answer (score 2):

You should not change the UI form background threads. This should be done only from the main thread. You can show a basic progress bar just before you start the background worker and hide it in the background worker RunWorkerCompleted event handler. To report real progress you need an implementation as Giorgi suggested.

Comment: this is exactly what i want to do.
but I watch for an fileChangedEvent. this is not raised in the main thread.

Comment: I do this:
private void OnFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
  // If I show my progressbar here nothing happens too
  this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens" ? Try to start the background worker backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); and on the next line show the progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

In order to report progress from the BackgroundWorker you need to call `ReportProgress` method from the `DoWork` event handler and show the progress in handler of [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx)

Comment: Also I think you should set the "ReportsProgress" property to "true".

Comment: I tried the progresschanged event also.
nothing happens. But i want to show my progressbar first, then i want to set the progress.

Comment: I set the ReportsProgress to true and the event raises but show doesn't do anything.

Comment: You should show progressbar before you start the work from main thread and do not touch it from the background thread as Adrian has said in his answer.